# Redux-saga POST method don't save the object in data base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my project I want to create a new soccer club.

I'm using redux-saga to POST a club, but in my redux-saga method `createCLub()`, his stop everytime in the `yield call(api.POST...)` and don't save in the data base (and never enter in the catch).

reducer.js

```
export function signUpClub({login, password, tradingName, corporateName, cnpj }) {
  return {
    type: '@auth/SIGN_UP_CLUB',
    payload: {
      login, password, tradingName, corporateName, cnpj
    },
  };
}
```

actions.js

```
export function* createClub({payload}){
  try{
    const { login, password, tradingName, corporateName, cnpj} = payload;

    const response = yield call(api.post, '/club', { login, password, tradingName, corporateName, cnpj});

    const { club } = response.data
    
     yield put(signUpClub(club));  
    history.push('/');
  } catch(err){
    toast.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using axios?

Comment: Yess, I'm using